# Find a pattern and replace an element of it

Tags: c#, csv

I have the following problem:

I am trying to split the rows of a CSV file but the thing is that sometimes I read the following line:

```
string input = "a,b,c,d,\"V=12.503,I=0.194\",e,f"
```

I use the following code

```
string[] SplittedLine= input.split(',');
```

The result is that i get an extra column because the data `\"V=12.503,I=0.194\"` has a comma inside, but when I open the CSV file with excel i noticed that Excel doesn't add an extra column because it doesn't split that data into two different data. How can I properly split this CSV file considering this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering commas in the "cells" of your CSV, which by convention (but not by any standard) are escaped by wrapping the cell data with double quotes. You also need to be aware that the quote-escaped string can contain quote literals.

Let's say you had a name column and someone's name was

> Jonathan "Jake" Smith, Jr.

That would be encoded as

> "Jonathan ""Jake"" Smith, Jr."

You can certainly improve your code to handle those cases. However, that problem has been solved before. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there are a number of solid open source libraries that handle the headache of parsing CSV files. The one I use is

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. the thing here is that i am already using my own library and i found this problem. i am looking for a way to detect his cases. i was thinking on look for the following pattern \"string\" and replace the comas for other character but i dont know a lot about patterns.

Comment: That won't work. You'll end up with `"a,b,c,d,V=12.503,I=0.194,e,f"` which has more columns than you expect. You need to properly handle the fact that double quotes around a cell mean that the commas between the double quotes are not cell separators but actual data.

Comment: I'm with the "don't reinvent the wheel" camp. Structured text parsing is not new. There are people who have optimised the solution and dealt with all the fringe cases. If you must do it yourself, maybe at the source of the many open ones to see how they handle the problems?

Comment: If you're asking me to write code that handles quotes for you, I'm not going to re-invent the wheel. If you want to give it a try yourself and get stuck, ask a new question about that new code and you'll find plenty of help.